# How to Select last checked checkbox dynamically using CSS?

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors, checked

I have lots of "checkbox"es in my page. I want to show(`display:block;`) a box, if the last "checkbox" of my page is checked, using CSS. The box is an immediate "textbox" after the last "checkbox".
It seems that `:last-child` is not working for `input[type="checkbox"]`. Even if it works, there will be another question: Can I use another selector (`:checked`) immediately after it(`:last-child`)?

Here is what I try to (but didn`t answer):

```
input[type = "checkbox"]:last-child:checked ~ input[type = "text"]{ display : block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using..  <strike>(I cannot test right now if it works)</strike>

```
input:checked:last-child
{
...
}
```

EDIT: I've corrected the selector and tested it. Works!  [Here a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/zPHm2/1/)

Comment: Inputs are empty elements, they can't contain any other elements.

Comment: Yeah but the OP isn't targeting the checkbox, he's targeting a text field that comes after the checkbox.

Comment: @conqenator: In HTML, `<input>` is just that by itself. You can't put any HTML inside it, e.g. `<input><span></span></input>` isn't valid HTML.

Comment: Then how will you specify that its a "checkbox". I mean, attributes are acceptable in your case, right?

Comment: @conqenator: Not possible with CSS, unfortunately. If the last checkbox has anything that comes after it but isn't a checkbox, `:last-child` won't select anything. And `:last-of-type` doesn't work with attribute selectors the way you think it would.

Comment: Oh, My bad. I think I realized something just now. Its very possible throught css though :)

Comment: If a textbox element is immediately preceded by a checkbox, you can use the CSS `+` operator. It selects the matched preceding sibling(s).

Comment: No, it selects what follows it. `A + B` selects `B`.